# how to deal jquery ajax with jsp for database update?

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, jsp, postback

I have used ajax with jquery and my ajax url is calling another jsp page which submits form data to database the problem is whenever I'm running the insert query, its replying "Null values can't be inserted to database" kinda exception, but whenever I'm reloading same page and clicking submit button, its getting submitted to database.
I think the problem is with something like postback method,
I'm new to ajax so please need your help...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#save').click(function ()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "test.jsp", //this is my servlet
                data: "input=" +$('#id').val()+"&output="+$('#op').val(),
                success: function(msg){      
                        $('#output').append(msg);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    input:<input id="id" type="text" name="" value="" /><br></br>
    output:<input id="op" type="text" name="" value="" /><br></br>
    <input type="button" value="save" name="save" id="save"/>
   <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

JSP:

```
<%@page import ="com.connectionUtil.ConnectionUtil"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<% String id = request.getParameter("input");
    try {
        Connection con = ConnectionUtil.getConnection();
        String sql = "insert into test(ID,...) values ('" + id + "',...)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException sqe) {
        out.println(sqe);
    }%> 
<body> <h4><%=id%> is stored </h4> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Where is the element with `id='call'`?

Comment: @anu sorry for mistake, I've edited it..

Comment: Check console for this ajax call and its response. It will give you more idea about this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ajax code is wrong. It should be like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "test.jsp", //this is my servlet
  data: {input : $('#id').val(), output: $('#op').val()},
  success: function(msg){      
      $('#output').append(msg);
  }
});
```

And then use the `request.getParameter("input")` to get the parameter value

**UPDATE** : Please note that i missed a comma (,) at the end of the line data:....

**UPDATE 2** : This is a working demo of your code without the connections to db...

index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#save').click(function ()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "test.jsp", //this is my servlet
                data: {
                    input: $('#id').val(), 
                    output: $('#op').val()
                },
                success: function(msg){      
                        $('#output').append(msg);
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    input:<input id="id" type="text" name="" value="" /><br></br>
    output:<input id="op" type="text" name="" value="" /><br></br>
    <input type="button" value="save" name="save" id="save"/>
   <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

test.jsp :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% String id = request.getParameter("input");
String output = request.getParameter("output");
%> 
<%=id%> is stored <br/>output is:<%=output%>
```

The first screen shows this:

[image]

And after inserting data and pressing `save` button it shows this:

[image]

Comment: The values are accessible when page is reloaded and submitted and another thing is I edited the code as you suggested, but No Change in output...

Comment: **Thanx MaVRoSCy...**
Your updated code is working.
thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I would not post this as an answer but I have to because I do not have the privilege in my account to post it as a comment but I as sure your confuse what to be click. The `#call` refers to the `element` `div` not the actual button but it will work either. Can you please post your `test.jsp` so that we can see the code because I suspect that there cause the problem.

I think you had edited your question so I think my answer is a wasteful.

Comment: `code`
    <%@page import ="com.connectionUtil.ConnectionUtil"%> 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<%         
String id=request.getParameter("input");
...    
    try{
            Connection con=ConnectionUtil.getConnection();
            String sql="insert into test(ID,...) values ('"+id+"',...)";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException sqe){ 
        out.println(sqe);
        }
 %>

<html>
    <body>
        <h4><%=id%> is stored </h4>
    </body>
</html>