# Updating database with jquery ajax for jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I wish to create a simple script to store information dynamically without refreshing or redirecting to another page. I've sourced high and low for answers before coming here, and I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783026/how-to-deal-jquery-ajax-with-jsp-for-database-update).

However, I'm still unable to get it to store data because I don't know where I've goen wrong. Also, I wish to ask the purpose of `success: function(msg)`

Thanks a lot!

### Update 1: Got it to work after following Anoop's solutions. However, such a [popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0cts.jpg) appears when the data is submitted

### StaffReg.jsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<title>Staff Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<%-- HTTP header --%>
<%response.addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
   response.addHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
    response.addHeader("Expires","0");  
 %>
<%-- Javascript --%> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#Register').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
     url: "StaffRegAuth.jsp",
     type: "post",
     data: {
   username: $('#username').val(),
   password: $('#password').val(),
   userGroup: $('#userGroup').val()
  },
     success: function(msg) {
  alert(msg);
     }
     });
});
});
</script>

<%-- Main body --%>
<h1 align="center"> Account Registration: </h1>
  <div align="center">
    <table style="width = 30%" >
      <tr>
        <td> User Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="username"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Password: </td>
        <td><input type="password" id="password"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <tr>
        <td> User Group: </td>
        <td><select name = "userGroup" id="userGroup">
            <option value="1">Administrator
            </optin>
            <option value="2">Clerk
            </optin>
            <option value="3">Operations
            </optin>
            <option value="4">Sales
            </optin>
          </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" id="Register">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## StaffRegAuth.jsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%-- Imports --%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%-- HTTP header --%>
<%response.addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
   response.addHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
    response.addHeader("Expires","0");  
    
 %>
<%-- Variables that will be written --%>
<% String sUsername = request.getParameter("username");
 String sPassword = request.getParameter("password");
 int sUserGroup = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userGroup"));
 %>
<%-- Creating new staff account - writing --%>
<%
 try{
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   String conURL= "jdbc:odbc:HOD_DATA";
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
   Statement st = con.createStatement();
   int status = st.executeUpdate("insert into Staff(username, password, user_group) values('"+sUsername+"','"+sPassword+"',"+sUserGroup+")");
   
   if(status>0){
    //out.println("Update sucessful");
   }
   else{
    //out.println("Update unsuccessful");
   }
   
   st.close();
   con.close();
   }
   
   catch(Exception e){
   out.println(e);
   }
   
  %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using jQuery selectors that target ID's (of #username, #password, etc) but you don't have any elements with those id's. So I'm guessing your username, password, and userGroup data fields return undefined?

Comment: Success function will be invoked when your request to your sevelt is successful. remove the "alert(msg)" to get rid of the popup menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the submit button and use a normal html button with Id as Register.
2. Modify your html input types and replace the name attribute with id attribute. Ex: use id="username" instead of name="username"

Debugging:
Use firebug to check what value is passed to server. Ensure the correct ajax request is submitted.

Hope it helps.